# Zweistellige Zahlen und Stellenwertsystem

Tags: numbers, mathematics

Im Deutschen werden ja bei den zweistelligen Zahlen die Einer vor den Zehnern ausgesprochen, während das für die höheren Stellen nicht mehr gilt, sodass es zu der unsystematischen Reihung *dreihundertsiebenundzwanzig* kommt.

Gibt es Untersuchungen, ob diese Anordnung das Verständnis des Stellenwertsystems bei Kindern erschwert oder verzögert?

Comment: Ich kann mir zumindest nicht vorstellen, dass das für Kinder komplizierter ist als das französische System - bis 69 noch relativ normal, dann geht es weiter bis neunzehnundsechzig, dann kommt vierzwanzig für 80, bis neunzehnundvierzwanzig für 99... (ja, von mir an die Vertauschung der zweiten Stelle im Deutschen angepasst - macht es Französischunkundigen vermutlich einfacher, zu verstehen (; ).

Answer (score 9):

Ja, gibt es:

[Zwanzigeins schlägt einundzwanzig](http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/mensch/0,1518,676719,00.html)

> So sehr sich amerikanische und europäische Kinder in Mathe-Tests anstrengen - ihre Altersgenossen aus China sind besser. Dank eines einfacheren Zahlensystems können sie schon früh besser zählen und rechnen. Sprachforscher glauben, dass die Methodik auch deutschen Kindern helfen würde.

Comment: Wobei es auch Studien gibt, die den Umfang des Alphabets und die Komplexität der Grammatik der Intelligenz der Erwachsenen gegenübergestellt werden. Soll heißen, wenn es einem als Kind sehr leicht gemacht wird, könnte (!) es sein, daß ihm später das Verstehen komplexer Zusammenhänge schwerer fällt.

Comment: Dass chinesische (und andere asiatische) Kinder in Mathematik leistungsstärker sind als europäische Kinder, glaube ich gerne. "Dank eines einfacheren Zahlensystems können sie schon früh besser zählen und rechnen" ist allerdings blanker Unsinn - der *Spiegel* möge mir das harte Urteil verzeihen. Das Zahlensystem ist heutzutage weltweit das gleiche, anders ist nur die *Sprechweise* der Zahlen. Das mag einen Einfluss auf die *Merkbarkeit* von Zahlen haben, allerdings ist das nur ein äußerst geringer Teil mathematischer Fähigkeiten. Aber in China wird intensiver gepaukt als bei uns.

Comment: Das gilt nicht nur für das Fach Mathematik, sondern für alle Fächer. Und wenn man sich als "Kulturpessimist" z.B. die Abituraufgaben in Mathematik im Laufe der Jahre ansieht, wird man feststellen müssen, dass das Niveau deutlich abgenommen hat .Außerdem ist auch die Rechtschreibfähigkeit geringer geworden.

Answer (score -1):

Ich denke, das ist komplizierter, als die Studien annehmen, da Zahlen bei uns von rechts nach links gelesen werden.

Einundzwanzig ist also richtig, da die 1 für 1 vor der 2 für 20 kommt.

Was die Studien testen, dürfte also eher sein, ob es einfacher ist, sich eine aus Ziffern zusammengesetzte Zahl von Ziffer für den größten Wert zur Ziffer für den kleinsten Wert vorzustellen oder umgekehrt.

Comment: Das stimmt so nicht, da es dann ja wie gesagt zu "dreihundertsiebenundzwanzig" kommt.

Comment: Ich sehe nicht, wie "dreihundertsiebenundzwanzig" obigem widerspricht. Ich habe ja schliesslich nicht gesagt, dass dreistellige Zahlen genauso richtig gelesen werden wie zweistellige.

Comment: ...und *genau das* führt verständlicherweise zu Verwirrungen :-)

Comment: Ich denke nur, dass die Verwirrung eher damit zu tun hat, dass die Woerter fuer die Zahlen voellig unabhaengig von den Zahlen sind. Woerter folgen weder der Leseweise von geschriebenen Zahlen, noch sind sie das genaue Gegenteil davon.