# Warum nennt man die Einer-Ziffer zuerst?

Tags: etymology, numbers

Im Deutschen nennt man die Zahl 65 "fünfundsechzig", also "5 und 60".
Man nennt also die rechte Ziffer zuerst - mit ein paar wenigen Ausnahmen (elf und zwölf z.B.)

Woher kommt diese Art der Aussprache?

Comment: Ähnlich, aber auf Englisch: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5009/why-are-german-numbers-backwards

Comment: Verwandte [Frage1](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1703/1696) und [Frage2](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/58569/1696).

Comment: Auch bemerkenswert auf English.SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/494702 und https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3903

Comment: [Four and twenty blackbirds baked in a pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sing_a_Song_of_Sixpence). (And for adults only: [Four and twenty virgins](https://genius.com/Bedlam-bards-the-ball-of-ballinor-lyrics).)

Comment: Also, "I am not one-and-twenty" is from Pride & Prejudice.

Comment: Selbst so [schlaue Dinge wie Computer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-Reihenfolge) wissen heute immer noch nicht, ob sie Zahlen von rechts nach links oder von links nach rechts lesen sollen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Kurze Antwort:**
Die Entwicklung der Art wie man Zahlen schreibt und die Entwicklung der Art wie man Zahlen ausspricht, haben voneinander unabhängig stattgefunden und haben nichts miteinander zu tun. Es gibt daher keinen Grund anzunehmen, dass es heute einen Zusammenhang geben sollte. Eventuell bestehende Ähnlichkeiten sind zufällig entstanden.

---

Warum nennt man die Zahl 13 auf englisch "thirteen" also "3 10" und warum 16 "sixteen" also "6 10"? Auch hier wird zuerst die Einerziffer ausgesprochen und dann erst die Zehnerstelle.

Warum wird auf französisch die Zahl 99 als "quatre vingts dix neuf" also "4 20 10 9" ausgesprochen ?

Warum wird im römischen Ziffernsystem die Zahl 9 als "IX" also "1 weniger als 10" geschrieben?

---

Unser gegenwärtig verwendetes Dezimalsystem stammt aus Indien und entstand dort ungefähr im 6. Jahrhundert unserer Zeitrechnung. Die Araber übernahmen dieses System, und erst ungefähr im 12. Jahrhundert kam dieses System nach Europa, mit Ziffern, die wir heute "arabisch" nennen (die aber in Wahrheit aus Indien stammen).

Über Zahlen gesprochen hat man in Europa aber schon sehr viel früher. Erst als man auch in Europa zu schreiben begann, entstand der Wunsch auch Zahlen niederzuschreiben. Bekannt ist in diesem Zusammenhang sicherlich das römische Zahlensystem, in dem man beispielsweise die Zahl 899 als "DCCCXCIX" geschrieben hat, also "500, 100, 100, 100, 10 weniger als 100, 1 weniger als 10". Es liegt wohl auf der Hand, dass diese Zahl in keiner Sprache so ausgesprochen wurde wie sie geschrieben wurde.

Die Germanen haben ja keine eigene Schrift entwickelt, sondern haben auf einen Schlag ungefähr im 2. Jahrhundert ein komplettes Alphabet mit 24 Zeichen (die Runen) von südlicheren Europäern übernommen und abgewandelt. Allerdings ist nicht ganz klar, ob der Ursprung der Runen das Alphabet der Etrusker, Latiner, Griechen oder Phönizier war, die um diese Zeit alle bereits miteinander verwandte Schriftsysteme in Verwendung hatten. Jedenfalls wurden in der Zeit, als Runen in Verwendung waren, Zahlen ebenfalls mit Runen geschrieben, nach einem System, das Ähnlichkeiten mit dem römischen System hatte. Allerdings nutzten die Germanen ihre Runen immer nur um kurze Inschriften auf Gegenständen zu hinterlassen. Es gibt keine längeren Texte in Runenschrift.

Ungefähr im 10. und 11. Jahrhundert wurden die Germanen christianisiert und übernahmen das lateinische Alphabet, um damit auch längere Texte zu schreiben. (Übrigens wurde erst um diese Zeit die germanische Mythologie, die bis dahin nur mündlich überliefert wurde, erstmals niedergeschrieben.) Bei dieser Gelegenheit begannen sie auch das römische Zahlensystem zu verwenden.

Zu dieser Zeit hatten sich die germanischen Sprachen aber bereits so weit differenziert, dass man Englisch und Deutsch als separate Sprachen betrachten muss (das war im 5. Jahrhundert noch nicht der Fall).

Und wie weiter oben erwähnt, wurde erst rund 200 Jahre danach jene Schreibweise von Zahlen eingeführt, die wir heute als selbstverständlich betrachten. Also zu einem Zeitpunkt, als es für dass Sprechen von Zahlen schon seit sehr langer Zeit weithin etablierte Regeln gab.

Bei den Germanen dürfte vor ihrer Bekehrung zum Christentum allerdings ein Zahlensystem in Verwendung gewesen sein, das nicht auf der Zahl 10 beruht, sondern auf der Zahl 12 bzw. zum Teil auch auf der Zahl 60. Daher haben die Zahlen 11 (*elf*) und 12 (*zwölf*) auch heute noch eigene Zahlwörter. Und nur deshalb kann Bilbo Beutlin am Beginn von "Herr der Ringe" seinen einundelfzigsten Geburtstag feiern. Hätten wir von Beginn am im Zehnersystem gerechnet und gedacht, gäbe es die Wörter *elf* (einzehn) und *zwölf* (zweizehn) gar nicht. (Ebenso auf Englisch: elf = eleven, zwölf = twelve, einundelfzig = eleventh-one, einzehn = oneteen, zweizehn = twoteen)

Auch Zahlwörter, die man in älteren Texten findet, und die zum Teil heute noch in Verwendung sind, stammen aus der Zeit vor der Einführung des Dezimalsystems:

> 12 = Dutzend
> 30 = Band, Bund
> 60 = Schock
> 120 = Großhundert
> 144 (12 x 12) = Gros

---

Als die Angeln und Sachsen auf die britischen Inseln übersiedelten, war die Aussprache der am häufigsten benötigten Zahlen, nämlich 1 bis 20, noch sehr eng verwandt mit der Sprechweise jener Germanen, die auf dem Festland blieben. Daher sind die entsprechenden Zahlwörter auch heute noch sehr ähnlich. Erst später, als die Völker geographisch getrennt waren und als sich ihre Sprachen bereits so sehr auseinander entwickelt hatten, dass man einander nicht mehr verstehen konnte, wandelte sich auf den britischen Inseln die Sprechweise der größeren Zahlen, während man auf dem Festland bis heute beim alten System bleib.

Comment: Whoever starts learning French will discover German is not the only language where wording the numbers is not intuative. And which covers the number 11 to 16 with own words, not combinations of "ten" (dix).

Comment: Take a look at Danish.

Answer (score 6):

Die Frage nach dem tieferen Grund für die deutsche Aussprache von Zahlen wird sich nicht mit Sicherheit beantworten lassen. Die Aussage

*Im Deutschen nennt man die Zahl 65 "fünfundsechzig", also "5 und 60". Man nennt also die rechte Ziffer zuerst.*

ist zwar korrekt, unterstellt aber im Grunde, dass

1. die Zahldarstellung "65" logisch ihrer sprachlichen Form vorausgeht,
2. die gewohnte Ziffernfolge "65" eine innere Notwendigkeit besitzt (und nicht etwa als "56" geschrieben werden könnte),
3. und die Ziffernfolge "65" aufgrund unserer Schreibrichtung zwangläufig von links nach rechts zu lesen und zu sprechen ist.

Nur wenn man diese Prämissen akzeptiert, stellt sich die Frage, warum wir im Deutschen Zahlen "falsch herum" aussprechen. Alle drei Prämissen sind jedoch unzutreffend.

Die Sprache kam vor der Schrift, in Worten gezählt wurde früher als mit Ziffern geschrieben -  die Frage ist also eigentlich

> Warum hat sich die Schreibweise der Zahlen von ihrer Sprechweise entfernt?

Die Zahlwörter von 11 - 99 "falsch herum" zu sprechen ist übrigens keineswegs ein Alleinstellungsmerkmal der deutschen Sprache. Die Zahlen 11 - 19 werden in den meisten Sprachen wie im Deutschen gesprochen. Im Lateinischen sind für die Zahlen 21 - 99 beide Varianten üblich (43 = quadraginta (et) tres / tres (et) quadraginta). Auch im Englischen war das früher einmal so. Im Arabischen ist es von 11 - 99 genauso wie im Deutschen.

Eine Divergenz von Sprache (Zahlwörtern) und geschriebenen Zahlen konnte überhaupt erst nach der Einführung eines *Stellenwertsystems für Zahlen* zutage treten.

Unser gewohntes Dezimalsystem enstand in Indien, verbreitete sich von dort nach Arabien und gelangte erst spät nach Europa. Wirklich durchgesetzt hat es bei uns sich erst mit dem Aufkommen des Buchdrucks im späten 15. Jahrhundert. Die verwendeten Ziffern 0 - 9 wurden bei ihrer "Importierung" zwar leicht verändert, bemerkenswert ist aber, dass die *Reihenfolge der Ziffern beim Schreiben* erhalten blieb obwohl die Schreibrichtung als solche genau umgekehrt ist. So wurde z.B. aus der arabischen Zahl ١٣٢٩ unsere 1329. Dasselbe Phämomen trat übrigens auf, als die Araber die Zahlen aus Indien übernahmen: Sanskrit wird von links nach rechts geschrieben, beim Import nach Arabien hätte man also eigentlich eine Umkehrung der Schreibrichtung auch für Zahlen erwarten können - was aber nicht erfolgte. Das deutet darauf hin, dass geschriebene Zahlen nicht als Worte oder Eigennamen aufgefasst wurden, die eine bestimmte Schreibrichtung haben und demgemäß bei Übertragung in ein Schriftsystem mit umgekehrter Schreibrichtung *anders herum* zu schreiben wären, sondern als Zeichenketten anderer (sprachunabhängiger) Provenienz.

Die Zahlworte "zehn", "hundert" und "tausend" (und ihre Entsprechungen in anderen Sprachen) zeigen, dass das Dezimalsystem gedanklich tief in der menschlichen Sprache verankert ist (zehn Finger zum Zählen, anschließend Bündelung in Potenzen von 10) und in dieser Form weit älter ist als das Konzept der geschriebenen Zahl. Tatsächlich kann unsere Sprache als Vorläuferin des Stellenwertsystems mit Basis 10 gesehen werden. In unserem gewohnten schriftlichen Dezimalsystem ergibt sich der Beitrag einer Ziffer zum Zahlenwert durch ihre Position *von rechts nach links gelesen*: Erste Ziffer von rechts = Anzahl Einer, zweite Ziffer von rechts = Anzahl Zehner, dritte Ziffer von rechts = Anzahl Hunderter usw. Erst diese Konvention liefert einen eindeutigen Zahlenwert, die Reihenfolge der Ziffern ist hier essenziell. Sprachlich wird das anders gelöst: Die Zehnerpotenz wird bei jeder Ziffer explizit mitgenannt. Beispiel: Geschrieben 2394 = 2 x 1000 + 3 x 100 + 9 x 10 + 4 x 1, gesprochen zwei **tausend** drei **hundert** vier [**eins** als 0-te Zehnerpotenz weggelassen] und neun **zig [ = zehn]**, auf englisch two **thousand** three **hundred** nine **ty [ = ten]** four [**one** als 0-te Zehnerpotenz weggelassen]. Insofern ist die Sprache flexibler als die Schrift, weil die Reihenfolge der Ziffern (z.B. in in 2394) im Grunde irrelevant ist. Im Gegenzug sind aber die Zahlworte deutlich länger als die gesprochene Folge der Ziffern z.B. "zwei - drei - neun - vier").

Im Dezimalsystem legt die allgemeinen Ausrichtung der Schrift von links nach rechts (z.B. europäische Sprachen) oder von rechts nach links (z.B. arabisch, hebräisch) automatisch auch eine Reihenfolge der Ziffern fest. Wichtig ist hier die **Interpretation dieser Reihenfolge**. Der Beitrag einer Ziffer zum Zahlenwert wird durch Multiplikation mit einer positionsabhängigen Zehnerpotenz gegeben. Bei unserer links-rechts-Ausrichtung ist die zugehörige Zehnerpotenz **in Schreibrichtung absteigend**. Im Arabischen ist dagegen die Zehnerpotenz **in Schreibrichtung ansteigend**. Ist es also wirklich **logisch**, dass "65" als "sechzig (und) fünf" gesprochen werden muss (absteigende Zehnerpotenzen), nur weil das unserer Schreibrichtung entspricht? Wie schon gesagt, die Sprache ging der Schrift voraus, und beim Sprechen scheinen mir ansteigende  Zehnerpotenzen ("fünf und sechzig") durchaus nicht unlogisch zu sein. Eine gewisse Inkonsequenz im Deutschen zeigt sich erst bei größeren Zahlen: 265 = "zweihundert fünf und sechzig" statt "fünf und sechzig und zweihundert".

Man könnte argumentieren, dass das Prinzip "absteigende Zehnerpotenz in Leserichtung" **beabsichtigt** ist, weil dann die erste Ziffer den größten Beitrag zur Zahl liefert, d.h. am wichtigsten ist. Dieses Argument ist jedoch nicht stichhaltig, weil unsere Zahlen nicht in dieser Absicht eingeführt wurden, sondern schlicht und einfach unter Beibehaltung ihres Aufbaus - ohne Richtungsumkehr - aus dem Arabischen übernommen wurden.

Eine interessante Frage bleibt:

> Warum ist die Sprechweise nicht in allen Sprachen einheitlich (wobei es nur um Reihenfolge von Einern und Zehnern geht)?

Eine Antwort habe ich nicht. Klar ist nur, dass die Sprachentwicklung nicht einheitlich verlief. Während z.B. im Englischen alte Formen wie "four and twenty" ausgestorben sind (vielleicht zugunsten einer "logischeren" Sprachstruktur), ist das im Deutschen nicht geschehen. Sind also manche Sprachen weniger flexibel in Hinblick auf "Optimierungen"? Interessant in diesem Zusammenhang ist, dass in Norwegen der Gesetzgeber im Jahre 1951 die althergebrachte Sprechweise nach deutschem Muster abgeschafft hat. [Zitat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegische_Sprache#Grundzahlen):

> Die nach schwedischem und englischem Muster gebildeten Zahlen des Typs Zehner + Einer, also etwa 51 – femtién/femtiéin, 52 – femtito, 53 – femtitre, 54 – femtifire, 55 – femtifem, 56 – femtiseks, 57 – femtisju, 58 – femtiåtte, 59 – femtini, wurden **1951 per Parlamentsbeschluss** offiziell eingeführt. Zuvor bildete man diese Zahlen offiziell wie im Dänischen und Deutschen, also Einer + og („und“) + Zehner: 51 – énogfemti/éinogfemti, 52 – toogfemti, 53 – treogfemti, 54 – fireogfemti, 55 – femogfemti, 56 – seksogfemti, 57 – sjuogfemti, 58 – åtteogfemti, 59 – niogfemti. In der gesprochenen Alltagssprache ist diese letztere Zählweise allerdings auch heute noch weit verbreitet; die meisten Menschen gebrauchen wechselweise das eine oder das andere System – nur bei den Telefonnummern hat sich das neue System vollständig durchgesetzt.

Die gewohnte Dezimalschreibweise von Zahlen hat übrigens m.E. einen nicht unerheblichen Nachteil: Wir lesen und sprechen Zahlen von links nach rechts, d.h. müssen zuerst den Stellenwert der ersten Ziffer von links bestimmen. Bei "kurzen" Zahlen wie 2394 ist das natürlich kein Problem, man sieht sofort, dass es sich um 2 Tausender handelt. Bei "langen" Zahlen wie 7519064818694001  ist das nicht mehr einfach (auch nicht in der Schreibweise 7.519.064.818.694.001), man muss erst die Anzahl der Stellen abzählen, um zu erkennen, dass es ich um 7 Billiarden handelt. Insofern wäre es durchaus eine Alternative, Zahlen andersherum zu schreiben, d.h. z.B. 100.496.818.460.915.7 statt 7.519.064.818.694.001, und dann problemlos "eins - sechshundertvierundneunzigtausend - achthundertachtzehn Millionen - vierundsechzig Milliarden - fünfhundertneunzehn Billionen - sieben Billiarden" zu sprechen. Dieser Vorschlag ist natürlich nicht umsetzbar, man bedenke aber, dass im Arabischen *aus Sicht des Lesers*, der von rechts nach links liest, Zahlen genau diesen Aufbau haben: Erste Ziffer in Leserichtung = Einer, zweite Ziffer in Leserichtung = Zehner usw. Unter diesen Aspekt sind allerdings die arabischen Zahlworte für größere Zahlen als 100 wieder unlogisch. Im früher entstandenen indischen Ziffernsystem wurden die Ziffern wie bei uns von links nach rechts in absteigender Folge der Zehnerpotenzen geschrieben, was eine getreue Übertragung der Namen der Ordinalzahlen in Sanskrit in eine Folge von Ziffernsymbolen darstellt. Hier ist wieder bemerkenswert, dass die Schreibrichtung der Sprechrichtung entgegengesetzt ist. Beispiel: Die Zahl 4769 wird in Sanskrit in aufsteigender Folge der Zehnerpotenzen gesprochen als "nava ṣaṣti saptaśata ca catur sahasra", wörtlich übersetzt "neun sechzig siebenhundert und vier Tausend". Es werden also Zahlen konsequent "falsch herum", d.h. entgegengesetzt der normalen Schreib- und Leserichtung, ausgesprochen.

Comment: @Jan Für "91" trifft das nicht zu, nur für "11 - 19".  Hier is es in der Tat in den meisten Sprachen so, dass erst der Einer gesprochen und dann die Zehn angehängt wird. "11" und "12" sind vielfach Sonderformen, aber auch hier steht der Einer verkappt vorne.

Comment: Aaaah, wer lesen kann, ist klar im Vorteil. Tschuldigung, der geht auf mich ^^'